# PLSQL procedure for deleting row in a table

Tags: oracle, plsql, delete-row

I have a table and I need to use a procedure that will delete a row named module in this table if it is named in the procedure I'm calling...
How can I do that?

```
table1:
id number
module varchar2
```

proc1:

```
input parameter --> module (optional)
if module exists then delete all rows in table1 named module
if module is null then truncate table1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the limited information that you provided, I have prepared a procedure `row_delete()` for your requirement:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE row_delete(
IN moduleName VARCHAR2(100))

BEGIN

DECLARE 
IF moduleName == NULL THEN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE table1';
   RETURN;
END IF;

SELECT count(module)
 INTO total
 FROM table1
 WHERE WHERE module = moduleName;

CASE total
   WHEN 0 THEN
       RAISE_ERROR(-6592, 'Expecting at least one row');
   WHEN when_expression_2 THEN 
       DELETE FROM table1 WHERE module = moduleName;
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Removed module: ' || moduleName);
   ELSE;
END CASE;
END
$$
```

Run this code in your database engine.
And when you call this procedure like:

```
CALL row_delete('module_name');
CALL row_delete(NULL);
CALL row_delete('XYY');
```

The row consisting `module_name` will be removed.

The NULL will result in Truncate Table.

And the other value parameter case raises an exception.

Thank you.

Comment: thx for the reply, however I meant that I need a procedure to delete a row in a table if the same module name is provided in procedure. If the parameter is null then to truncate that table. and if the module name in parameter is not the same as in the table then raise error and do nothing.

Comment: Sorry. That doesn't make sense.
I don't understand the one you said like - "if the same module name is provided in procedure"
Please make it clear.

Comment: If I say: procedure1 (modulname) then I want row with that modulename from a table deleted. If I say: procedure1 (null) then i want the whole table1 truncated. If I say: procedure1 (xyy) and there is no module named as xyy in a table1 then I want to raise an error and don't do anything.

Comment: A note for the other readers. The PL/SQL code in the answer in not valid but has several (syntax) errors. Instead consider it as a pseudo-code only.

Comment: I agree. Thanks  user272735.

Comment: note, if you have millions of rows than you should use "create temp table -> rename table" combo instead of delete because of performance & time